How to pass HTTP headers to WCF service calls from AjaxWebService(Ajax-enabled) in existing project?
We have an ASP.NET web application that consumes WCF services. The current system structure is as follows:
In AjaxWebService.svc.cs:
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

private Service m_Service;
private Service Service
{
    get
    {
        if (m_Service == null)
        {
            m_Service = new Service();
        }
        return m_Service;
    }
}

 [OperationContract]
internal Users[] getUsers()
{
    return this.Service.getUsers();
}
 [OperationContract]
internal products[] getproducts()
{
    return this.Service.getproducts();
}

In Service.cs:

private IServiceClient m_ServiceGateway;
private IServiceClient ServiceGateway
{
    get
    {
        if (m_ServiceGateway == null)
        {
            m_ServiceGateway = new IServiceClient();
        }
        return m_ServiceGateway;
    }
}

internal Users[] getUsers()
{
    return this.ServiceGateway.getUsers(this.RoleId, this.Token);
}

internal products[] getproducts()
{
    return this.ServiceGateway.getproducts(this.RoleId, this.Token);
}

In IServiceGateway.cs:
[OperationContract]
List<getUsers> getUsers(int RoleId, string Token);
[OperationContract]
List<products> getProducts(int RoleId, string Token);


Problem:
I want to pass custom HTTP headers (like User-Agent and Accept) to WCF service calls without changing the existing method signatures (e.g., return this.ServiceGateway.getUsers(this.RoleId, this.Token); and return this.ServiceGateway.getproducts(this.RoleId, this.Token);).
I’ve tried to initialize and pass headers within the ServiceGateway property like this:
private IServiceClient m_ServiceGateway;
private IServiceClient ServiceGateway
{
    get
    {
        if (m_ServiceGateway == null)
        {
            m_ServiceGateway = new IServiceClient();
            using (new OperationContextScope(m_ServiceGateway.InnerChannel))
            {
                // Set HTTP headers
                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestProperty.Headers["User-Agent"] = "mrt/1.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)";
                httpRequestProperty.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
            }
        }
        return m_ServiceGateway;
    }
}


However, the headers are not being passed correctly to the WCF service.
Question:
Is there a way to pass these headers to the WCF service without changing the existing method calls like return this.ServiceGateway.getUsers(this.RoleId, this.Token);? How can I apply custom headers centrally to all WCF service calls without modifying every API?

since you tagged this javascript, this comment is assuming the client is a browser. Doesn't a browser already send accept/user-agent headers? Why do you wish to spoof the user-agent anyway?

I guess my mentioning browser and javascript has confused you - is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79026678/how-to-pass-user-agent-header-to-wcf-service-callajax-enabled-from-javascript

You can create CustomMessageInspector to implement this feature. Here is related post you can check first.
CustomMessageInspector.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfHeaderDemo
{
    public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;

            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                httpRequestMessage = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
            }

            // Add custom header here
            httpRequestMessage.Headers["User-Agent"] = "mrt/1.0";
            httpRequestMessage.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

            return null;
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }
    }

}

CustomEndpointBehavior.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfHeaderDemo
{
    public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
    }

}

Use it
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(/* Parameters */);  
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(/* Service Behavior */); 

Related doc :
Configuring and Extending the Runtime with Behaviors - Service Behaviors
